# Property is incompatible with index signature

Tags: typescript

```
const test = [
    {
        "a": 1
    },
    {
        "b": 1
    }
]
interface t {
    [key: string]: number
}
const ttt: t[] = test
```

Property '"b"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
it works if I rename the key either b or a both of same key.

Comment: Remove the type annotation.

Answer (score 13):

Because `test` doesn't have a type, it's being inferred to this type:

```
({ a: number; b?: undefined; } | { b: number; a?: undefined; })[]
```

`test` is then assigned to `ttt`, but it's not compatible to have a possibly undefined `b` key in the new interface `t`.

You can fix this by add the type directly to `test`:

```
const test: t[] = [
    {
        "a": 1
    },
    {
        "b": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. another question is 
support that test is imported from other part 
import test from 'data.json'. how do we move ahead

Comment: You'd just need to make sure that you're setting the type like this where the `test` variable is created. The type will be kept when you import it from another file.